# Jquery 2.0.3 append items not working

Tags: jquery, append

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.todo a.edit').on('click',function(){

    var container = currentTODO.find('.text');


    $('<input   type="text">').val(container.text()).appendTo(container.empty());

    // Appending the save and cancel links:
    container.append(
        '<div class="editTodo">'+
            '<a id="saveChanges" href="#">Save</a> or <a id="discardChanges" href="#">Cancel</a>'+
        '</div>'
    );

});

   $( ".editTodo" ).on('click',(function() {
            console.log( $(this) );
    }));
```

the .on('click'... or any other event that I try use on the appended items do not trigger anything.
have no idea why.

it worked before on jquery 1.7

Comment: Looks like it's working with some html: https://jsfiddle.net/cdfyha9p/

Comment: I tried this, but changing the console.log to alert it didnt work.
    $(".editTodo").on('click', (function() {
 alert($(this));
}));

Comment: Could you update the jsfiddle with the non-working scenario and post the link. Just hit the update button in the top bar.

Comment: I did, but with the event delegation aproach worked. My problem is on WHY it didnt work on 203 when trying on 1.7 it was good. I had to change some outdated function from 1.7 but it should have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation

```
$('body').on('click','.todo a.edit',function(){
var container = currentTODO.find('.text');
container.empty();
var text = container.text();
$('<input>',{value:text}).appendTo(container);
container.append(
    '<div class="editTodo"><a id="saveChanges" href="#">Save</a> or <a id="discardChanges" href="#">Cancel</a></div>');

});


  $('body').on('click',".editTodo" ,function() {
            console.log( $(this) );
    });
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/wsghquns/

Answer (score 0):

Please see carefully:

Your code :

```
$( ".editTodo" ).on('click',(function() {
            console.log( $(this) );
});
```

Correction code :

```
$(".editTodo").on('click',function() {
            console.log( $(this) );
});
```

You can used a extra `(` after `'click',`

Full correction code bellow :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.todo a.edit').on('click',function(){
    var currentTODO = $('.todo')
    var container = currentTODO.find('.text');
    $('<input   type="text">').val(container.text()).appendTo(container.empty());

    // Appending the save and cancel links:
    container.append(
        '<div class="editTodo">'+
            '<a id="saveChanges" href="#">Save</a> or <a id="discardChanges" href="#">Cancel</a>'+
        '</div>'
    );
    });

  $( ".editTodo" ).on('click',function() {
    console.log( $(this) );
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I did notice that. but the main issue remained.

Comment: Welcome, main issue remained? you may tell me that?